# Nested loop GridView not working in C#

Tags: c#, loops, gridview, nested, nested-loops

Some idea why my code stop in the first row? My row have 35 columns (12 rows). I want check every column in row if is boolean, and check a value in cell. But this code make everything ok just in the first row, and dont't go to the next:

```
        foreach (DataRow row in pptesteDataSet.Tables["Atividade"].Rows)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < gridView3.Columns.Count; t++)
            {
                if (gridView3.Columns[t].ColumnType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    string rou = Convert.ToString(gridView3.Columns[t]);
                    gridView3.SetFocusedRowCellValue(rou, false);
                }
            }
        }
```

I had maked this, and doon't worked to:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < gridView3.DataRowCount; i++)
            {
                    for (int t = 0; t < gridView3.Columns.Count; t++)
                    {
                        if (gridView3.Columns[t].ColumnType == typeof(bool))
                        {

                            if (barCheckItem1.Checked)
                            {
                                string row = Convert.ToString(gridView3.Columns[t]);
                                gridView3.SetFocusedRowCellValue(row, true);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string row = Convert.ToString(gridView3.Columns[t]);
                                gridView3.SetFocusedRowCellValue(row, false);
                            }
                        }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET or Winform?

Answer (score 0):

Just works if i put gridview.movenext():

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView3.DataRowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridView3.VisibleColumns.Count; j++)
            {
                if (gridView3.Columns[j].ColumnType == typeof(bool))
                {
                    string row = Convert.ToString(gridView3.Columns[j]);
                    gridView3.SetFocusedRowCellValue(row, false);
                }
            }
            gridView3.MoveNext();
        }
```